# Access session data from Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, session, vuejs2

I try to access data from session, but I don't get anything.

In Controller I use:  `session()->get('cas_user') ?? "";` , and I get some date.

In Vuejs I try this: `this.$session.get('cas_user')` , and I don't get anything.
Also `this.$session.exists()` is false.

I have vue-session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you initialized a session before accessing its values (that is why `this.$session.exists()` returns `false`)?

```js
this.$session.start()
```

Have you saved something inside the `'cas_user'` key before trying to get it?

```js
this.$session.set('cas_user', value)
```

You can also try `this.$session.getAll()` to see if ther is some data saved in the session.