# Laravel and Vue.js accessing a session variable. Is there a better way?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, session

I need to store a session variable in my app. In the Laravel controller I do something like this:

```
if (!session('xyz')) {
  session(['xyz' => 'ABC']);
}
```

Since I'm using `Inertia`, I render the component like:

```
return Inertia::render('Comp')
    ->with('xyz', session('xyz'));
```

Then in the componet I read the session variable with `this.$page.props.xyz`

The code works, but since I'm pretty novice in VueJS, I was wondering if this is correct, or if there's some other better way.

Right now than I'm using a pair of variables, I think is okay, but having more and more, my code will have lots of `->with()`s

Related to this, I read this question: [Access session data from Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506737/access-session-data-from-vuejs) but I didn't know where to use the `this.$session.start()`, I placed it in the `mounted()` section of my component, but it threw an error: `app.js:20517 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')`

So I feel there must be a better way, I think using the `$session` object might be the right thing to do.